# Which keycloak endpoints should I use?

Tags: keycloak-rest-api

I'd like to use keycloak to role base access control. I don't understand very well how key cloak works so far.

I can get an access_token by following command.

```
curl \
-d "username=admin" \
-d "password=MY_PASSWORD" \
-d "client_id=MY_CLIENT" \
-d "grant_type=password" \
"https://MY_DOMAIN/auth/realms/MY_REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

My WebAPI is made by rocket (rust). So there is no prepared keycloak adapter.

I think I need check the given token by client  on each access to my WebAPI.

This is my handler.

```
///handler
#[get("/")]                                                                                
pub fn myhandler(_key:ApiKey,conn: DbConn) -> Option<JsonValue> 

pub struct ApiKey(String); 
impl<'a, 'r> FromRequest<'a, 'r> for ApiKey {                                                                                                                                                               
    type Error = ApiKeyError;                                                                                                                                                                               

    fn from_request(request: &'a Request<'r>) -> request::Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {                                                                                                                      
        let keys: Vec<_> = request.headers().get("x-api-key").collect();                                                                                                                                    
        //ask keycloak server that keys[0] is valid access_token??                                                                                                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

I found there are some endpoints on keycloak. Which should I use?

```rust
{

    // some claims are expected here

    // these are the main claims in the discovery document about Authorization Services endpoints location
    "token_endpoint": "http://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "token_introspection_endpoint": "http://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
    "resource_registration_endpoint": "http://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm}/authz/protection/resource_set",
    "permission_endpoint": "http://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm}/authz/protection/permission",
    "policy_endpoint": "http://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm}/authz/protection/uma-policy"
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? you used the right end point which is the token end point. yes you need a token before accessing the keycloak REST Api. Send this token in the Authorization header of the API requests (Authorization: Bearer {token}). The token expires after a minute by default. But you can change this in the realm settings from the admin console.